# Positive lag-1 autocorrelation after differencing a stationary time series

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation

In the following post it is trying to explain why the lag-1 autocorrelation is negative after first differencing a stationary time series.

[Why does differencing time-series introduce negative autocorrelation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77593/why-does-differencing-time-series-introduce-negative-autocorrelation)

It argues that $\psi_j$ are decreasing and less than one. However, if we consider ARMA(1,1) with $\theta = 0.5$ and $\phi = 0.9$, above claim violates and lag-1 auto correlation is not negative. Because $\psi_j = 1.4(0.9)^{j-1}$ for $j \geq 1$.

Does anyone know whether the explanation given in this post holds for specific cases?

---

Edited:

If $\{X_t\}$ is a mean zero stationary time series with autocovariance function $\gamma(h)$. Let $Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$.

\begin{align*}
Cov(Y_t, Y_{t-1}) & = Cov(X_t - X_{t-1}, X_{t-1} - X_{t-2})\\
& = \gamma(1) - \gamma(2) - \gamma(0) + \gamma(1)\\
& = -\gamma(0)[1 - 2\rho(1) + \rho(2)].
\end{align*}

Variance of $Y_t$:
\begin{align*}
Var(Y_t) & = 2[\gamma(0) - \gamma(1)]\\
&= 2\gamma(0)[1 - \rho(1)] 
\end{align*}

where $\rho(h) = \frac{\gamma(h)}{\gamma(0)}$.

Then autocorrelation function of $Y_t$ is
\begin{align*}
Corr(Y_t, Y_{t-1}) &= \frac{Cov(Y_t, Y_{t-1})}{\sqrt{Var(Y_t)Var(Y_{t-1})}}\\
& = -\frac{1 - 2\rho(1) + \rho(2)}{2(1 - \rho(1))}.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
-\rho(1) & < \rho(2) < \rho(1)\\
1 - \rho(1) & < 1 + \rho(2) < 1 + \rho(1)\\
1 - 3\rho(1) & < 1 - 2\rho(1) + \rho(2) < 1 - \rho(1)\\
\frac{1 - 3\rho(1)}{2(1 - \rho(1))} & < \frac{1 - 2\rho(1) + \rho(2)}{2(1 - \rho(1))} < \frac{1}{2}\\
-\frac{1}{2} & < -\frac{1 - 2\rho(1) + \rho(2)}{2(1 - \rho(1))} < -\frac{1 - 3\rho(1)}{2(1 - \rho(1))}\\
-\frac{1}{2} & < Corr(Y_t, Y_{t-1}) < -\frac{1 - 3\rho(1)}{2(1 - \rho(1))}
\end{align*}

So, I think it is not always the case that the lag-1 autocorrelation of the differenced series is negative. But, if it is negative it can't exceed -0.5, which sometimes used to identify over-differenced series.

Any feedback about this procedure?